# reboot does not work after setting OTP to USB host boot mode

Tags: reboot

On an Rpi 3 model B V1.2, I changed the OTP to boot from usb device like [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md).

It works as it should but if I issue a "sudo reboot now" command, the computer shuts down but doesn"t reboot. If power cycle, it boots again.

What should I do?

**Update** with info from comments:
In facts, sometimes it reboots, sometimes no. I wonder if it could be a temperature issue.

This is a clean lite version of the os. On usb ports, I have a wired keyboard and an ssd to boot on. I also tried adding a "timeout" file on the SD, like suggested in the link in the original post. Power supply is a rpi original.

The system rebooted correctly with the sd AND the USB drive when system was on the sd.

Comment: The now is redundant and ignored in reboot.  What happens if you try `sudo shutdown -r`?  The pi should reboot in a minutes time.

Comment: It shuts down. No reboot.

Comment: Can you try with a clean Lite version of the OS with nothing in the USB?  It could be a start up power issue - what do you have plugged in and what is the power supply you are using?

Comment: this is a clean lite version of the os. On usb ports, I have a wired keyboard and an ssd to boot on. I also tried adding a "timeout" file on the SD, like suggested in the link in the original post.

Comment: Power supply is a rpi original.

Comment: What about a reboot with the SD card only (nothing in USB) - it maybe the drive is pulling too much with the keyboard - what drive / keyboard are you using?

Comment: The system reboots correctly with the sd AND the USB drive when system is on the sd. I can't do your test because now (and this is the difference) system is on the USB drive.

Comment: In facts, sometimes it reboots, sometimes no. I wonder if it could be a temperature issue.

Comment: What do you have on the SD card is the OS is on the USB drive?  The PI normally throttles well (esp models that are not the 4) to keep the CPU/GPU running.  Ive had them over 70C and working OK.